# Pattern in variable with sed

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed

I have in a file with text with the name test.txt in path d:\test\
this file have different text example:

```
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
Presents: d:\test\asdf\bla
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
exampel blas asdlkwe3 asd f3 234 df
```

In the file test.txt if a line with the "Presents: d:\test\asdf\bla" 
and I need d:\test\asdf\bla as variable. Only Presents: its always same. Next word can something else

d:\test\addons\sed.exe is correct.

```
@echo off
if "%aufruf%"=="" (
SETLOCAL
)

set 1=
set file=d:\test\test.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("d:\test\addons\sed.exe" -n /Presents:/P %| 
"d:\test\addons\sed.exe" "s/Presents: //g" %file%) do set 1=%%a
echo %1%
pause
```

As you can see below, the output is empty:

```
d:\test>test2.bat

d:\_test>
```

Comment: Use variablenames that start with alphabetics, not digits. %0..%9 refer to the arguments supplied to the routine.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
if "%aufruf%"=="" (
SETLOCAL
)

set data=
set file=d:\test\test.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=1*delims= " %%a in ("d:\test\test.txt") do if "%%a"=="Presents:" set data=%%b
echo %data%
pause
```

Separate the file on spaces (the `delims` value) into tokens; the first goes to `%%a` and the second (remainder of the line) to `%%b`.

if `%%a` is `Presents:` then assign `%%b` to `data`.

Show `data`

Answer (score 0):

On topic windows/batch-file solutions:

Using sed ([gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)) :

```
@echo off
set "data=n/a"
set "file=.\test.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'sed -n "s/^Presents: //p" "%file%"'
) do set "data=%%a"

echo %data%

pause
```

Pure batch replace the three lines `for /f .. do`

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%a in (
    'findstr /I "^Presents:" %file%'
) do set "data=%%b"
```

Using PowerShell replace the three lines `for /f .. do`

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (
    `powershell -NoP -C "sls '(?<=^Presents: )(.+)$' '%file%'|%%{$_.matches.groups[1].value}"`
) do set "data=%%a"
```

Answer (score -1):

so, if you got unix-style `sed` on your machine, why are you writing windows batch files? Go directly for bash scripts and run them with `bash` instead of `cmd`.

Anyway, you need to first remove all irrelevant lines, then remove the `Presents:` from the remainder.

```
grep '^Presents: ' test.txt | sed 's/Presents: //'
```

I'm not fluent in cmd batch files, but a shell script would look something like this to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

magicstring="Presents: "
outvariable=$(grep "^$magicstring" < $1 | sed "s/$magicstring//")
echo $outvariable
```

Comment: i will use this in a .bat for windows. it is part of a larger bat file, i can not change to bash

Comment: In that case: good luck :) I'm not an avid cmd/batch programmer, but I remember that even as a kid, I was disappointed by how inelegant the shell language was. Imagine my surprise when I got my hands on a [Tomsrtbt](http://www.toms.net/rb/) floppy disk, and suddenly had a shell that was *so much more awesome*. Especially long, complex cmd scripts are candidates for a rewrite in a better shell, or even a proper scripting language, imho. But that's really up to your use case!

Comment: There's been a downvote, which is democratically very fine, but it'd be nice to get a commend explaining *why* and what I could *improve*.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but `outvariable=$(grep "^$magicstring" < $1 | sed "s/$magicstring//")` should be `outvariable=$(sed -n "s/^$magicstring//p" "$1")` since you never need both grep and sed, and `echo $outvariable` should be `echo "$outvariable"` since you should always quote your variables unless you are specifically intending to invoke globbing, word splitting, filename expansion, etc..